# How can i prevent Members of a SharePoint Group to see other members of the same group?

Tags: 2013, security, spgroup

How can i prevent Members of a SharePoint Group to see other members of the same group?

The user should not see other members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.  The only control SharePoint allows is for preventing non-members from seeing who is a member of a particular group.

There are of course various CSS and javascript tricks you could do to make it difficult, but this would not be truly secure.

I'm curious on your use case for needed to conceal the identities of others in the same SP group.

One alternative to consider is using Active Directory groups instead of SP groups, since SharePoint doesn't allow anyone to see the memberships of AD groups via SharePoint.

Comment: Hi Jim. Its the following use case: i have many suppliers which are in the same group cause it makes no sense to have a group for each supplier (its hard to maintain this). But i dont want that the supplier knows of each other.

Comment: That sounds like more of a "hide" than a true secure.  In that case, you can just make it difficult for them to stumble upon the membership lists.  You can use CSS to simply hide the SharePoint navigational elements that take you to the membership groups.  Of course, you will need access to the master page to be effective at this, rather than having to add CSS to every page...